# inttypes.h: What are the reasons behind PRIdN (for N <= 16 bits)

Tags: c

`inttypes.h` is a header that defines portable `printf` specifiers for the types `intN_t`, `int_leastN_t` and `int_fastN_t` etc.

I'm not interested about the `PRIdLEASTN` and `PRIdFASTN` definitions, as I never use the types `int_leastN_t` and `int_fastN_t`.

However, I regularly use `intN_t` resp. `uintN_t`, so I'm interested to know what the rationale behind the macros `PRIdN` and `PRIuN` are.

More specifically, I'm interested in `PRIu8` `PRIu16` and their signed counterparts.

Why?

[This site](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/inttypes.h.html) says:

> The ISO/IEC 9899:1990 standard specified [...] but placed very little requirement on their size other than that **int** and **short** be at least 16 bits and **long** be at least as long as int and not smaller than 32 bits.

(emphasis not mine)

This means `int` is always equal or bigger than 16 bits.

Variadic functions use integer promotion if a type smaller than `int` is given.

So if a type smaller than `int` is specified, it automatically gets promoted to an `int`.

Why is then, that `PRIu8`, `PRId8` are made available, if variadic functions will never be able to accept a **fixed** 8 bit value?

It's standard to specify a signed integer (`int`) with `%d` and an unsigned integer with `%u` (`unsigned int`), so why the macros?

Comment: Completeness? Makes it easier to write code that operates on all fixed-size integers without having to special-case `int8_t` and `int16_t`. `#define PrintNBitInteger(n, v) printf(PRId##n, (int##n##_t)v)`